# Parallel processing through spring integration router

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How i have a requirement where splitter has collection of 10 objects. Each of the object is given to the respective spring integration router based on some criteria. now is there any befault router available so that all channels should work parallely or any other custom way to achieve parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

There is just enough to make the splitter `output-channel` as `ExecutorChannel` - and all your splitted message will be processed parallely in the downstream. If all other channels are `direct`, of course...

With an `ExecutorChannel` messages are shifted to the separate independent Thread.

That's all.